# PHP POST Method is not receiving data from ajax POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I have checked thoroughly through my code and I am not seeing the problem. Looked for other questions similar to mine and found that most just skipped `$_POST['something']` parts. Here is what I have for ajax:

```
$(document).on('click','#smallbtn',function(){

        var postuserid = $(this).data("postuserid");
            $post = $(this);
            console.log($(this).data("postuserid"));

        $.ajax({

            url: 'cooking.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'postuserid': postuserid
            },

        });
    });
```

Most answers said that to use `$(document).on('click','#smallbtn',function()`. When before I just used `$(documemt) ready`. (Which console logged as soon as I entered the page.) Through jQuery, I am using the latest `.data` when before I used `.attr`. Both gave me the same and correct result in the `console.log`. Here is my PHP:

```
$uid = $_POST['postuserid'];
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "testdb");
        $ssql = "SELECT * FROM mainid WHERE postid='$uid'";
        $rresult = mysqli_query($db,$ssql);
        while($lrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rresult)){
            echo $lrow['smallid'];
            echo '<br>';
        }
```

I am not sure what's going on here because I do have the correct `$_POST['postuserid']`. And lastly:

```
echo '<a  href="#" data-postuserid="'.$row['id'].'" id="smallbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#small"  data-modal="small">';
```

There has to be something I am doing wrong here, any help is appreciated!

**UPDATE: The data is visible in the console log, but not visible in the modal.**

**UPDATE 2: The data is just not visible for some reason whether it is in the modal or not. But it is in the console.**

**UPDATE 3: `poseruserid` is not being set in the POST Method and the query is not receiving anything.**

Comment: data: { 'postuserid': postuserid}, use double quote in the data:  { "postuserid": postuserid}

Comment: Double quotes, single quotes, no quotes on the keyname makes zero difference.

Comment: So what is the problem @Laney? You say the console shows the right id, and you say you do have the correct `$_POST['postuserid']` ... so what actually is NOT working? After you do get it working, be sure to look into and use **prepare** for statements, instead of directly putting the variable in the sql. That is to protect you from sql injection attacks.

Comment: still has difference, the standard in JSON.

Comment: @IncredibleHat The problem is that nothing is showing when I echo the `echo $lrow['smallid'];` I know there is data in the database and when I do the GET Method i.e ?id=14 in the database, the data shows in my modal.

Comment: @bdalina it be the acceptable way in JSON, but this is not JSON, this is an object in javascript. Even jquery's own documentation site uses the 'no quotes' method for keynames: `data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }`

Comment: @LaneyWilliams so when you say you do have `$_POST['postuserid'];` ... how did you test that to know you do have it? Try to `print_r($_POST);` at the top of your php to see if in fact you do have it. If you DO, then the issue is in the db lookup. PS: in your `.ajax` you have no `success:` defined to handle the return... is that intentional?

Comment: @IncredibleHat I got this: `Array ( )` from the `print_r`. Maybe it's a localhost issue? But then again, my other POST methods works in the localhost. And also, I don't think it's my `$(this).data("postuserid")` because my console log results are correct.

Comment: if you will add a success(){ },and  error(){ } in ajax it might help atleast in someway

Comment: Weird one. The code as presented 'should work' ... so the issue has to be the result of something not shown here. Really, you SHOULD have a POST value with those ajax settings... especially if the id is showing in the console when it calls the ajax method. Watch your network tab closely, look at the request data, and response data, and make certain no redirects are happening anywhere in the mix too.

Comment: success:function(data)
                    {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error:function(data)
                    {
                         $( document ).ajaxError(function( event, request, settings )
                        {
                        console.log('Sorry, we are having a trouble in this url '+settings.url)
                         }  }  not sure if having trouble in the post address

Comment: @bdalina I'll try that. But back to the php problem, this is really all I have. My `like` system  post methods are the exact same as this one. Yes, it is weird.

Comment: Can you screenshot the network tab and see the header? or whats inside the header, near console tab, sources, and the header if the script is 200 status

Comment: When I inserted your code above, I got an unexpected syntax error

Comment: Actually, nevermind it prints the my entire code in the console log @bdalina

Comment: I don't know how it gives you a syntax error, but you can view my simple working code,  here https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/376638/

Comment: @bdalina Ok. I copied your error handling code and I still got the success where it shows me all of my code in console. If I can't do this in the POST method, how would I go about doing it in the GET Method?

Comment: they are almost the same, just change the type: "POST" to type:"GET"

Comment: use this to test if there is really some data being pass in the post, echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>";

Comment: @bdalina yeah, I don't think anything is getting passed. I got this : `array()`

Comment: if you can check the network tab you'll see the data which is being sent, just near the console tab, sources then, the network tab and click the cooking.php check if its status is 200 then click the header, you'll see what you need there if it really sending the data you want yo pass

Comment: Another test I did was `if (empty($_POST))` before the `print_r` and same results.

Comment: OK I checked the Network: `Status Code: 200 OK` Sent: `postuserid: 14`

Comment: there must be something wrong, Try this print_r($_REQUEST);

Comment: If it doesn't work still, then try this <?php var_dump($GLOBALS); ?> see if the POST, and REQUEST are present

Comment: With `$_REQUEST` it showed me what I had in my session which was `[username] => AParr1337` and `$GLOBALS` showed a huge list of I guess things  that I am pulling from the mysql database

Comment: Could it be that Ajax is not dynamic? Or the placement of my php code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174596/discussion-between-bdalina-and-laney-williams).